# Accessing entire hash in context inside block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

Say I have this hash:

```
hash = { :c => "three", :a => "one", :b => "two" }
```

And I want to have this at the end:

```
one, two, three
```

Now say that this is well nested inside a different hash. I want to avoid things like:

```
puts "#{bigger_hash[0].hash[:a]}, #{bigger_hash[0].hash[:b]}, #{bigger_hash[0].hash[:c]}"
```

I know there's this form for `map` which lets me do something like this without defining the order:

```
bigger_hash[0].hash.map{|k,v| v}.join(', ')
```

Which will output:

```
three, one, two
```

Which removes flexibility. I want to explicitly address these in the order I want (not necessarily numerical or alphabetical!)

Is there a convenience method I can use to achieve this? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
bigger_hash[0].hash.magic{"#{a}, #{b} #{c}"}
# or
bigger_hash[9].hash.magic(:a, :b, :c).join(', ')
```

Comment: What is `bigger_hash` and what does `bigger_hash[0]` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is your ans :

```
bigger_hash[9].hash.values_at(:a, :b, :c).join(', ')
```

Comment: what is `bigger_hash` ??

Comment: i am guessing that user have some big hash. But @ChenAsraf give you better answer what exactly it is.

Comment: `bigger_hash` doesn't matter as much as it just explains why I don't want to use the whole hash path when I reference it in a string. Anyways, `values_at` is exactly what I was looking for, and solves my problem perfectly! Looks like you beat @GaganGami by about 8 seconds, so you get the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

what is `bigger_hash` returns?  I am not sure what you are looking for but as I understood you want to sort your hash by `keys` and return it's `values`. Check this:

```
> hash = { :c => "three", :a => "one", :b => "two" }
> hash.sort.map{|e| e[1] }.join(' , ')
 => "one , two , three"  # your expected output
```

**OR**

```
> hash.values_at(:a, :b, :c).join(', ')
=> "one, two, three"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this type:

```
hash = { :c => "three", :a => "one", :b => "two" }
Hash[hash.sort].values.join(", ")
# => "one, two, three"
```

But map method is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one should define the sorting function:

```
sorter = lambda { |o1, o2| o1 <=> o2 }
```

Then you are able to get values sorted as you wanted:

```
hash = { :c => "three", :a => "one", :b => "two" }
hash.sort(&sorter).to_h.values.join(', ')
#⇒ one, two, three
```

E.g. for reverse order we get:

```
sorter = lambda { |o1, o2| o2 <=> o1 }
hash.sort(&sorter).to_h.values.join(', ')
#⇒ three, two, one
```

Legacy rubies don’t have `#to_h` method:

```
hash.sort(&sorter).map(&:last).join(', ')
```

Inplace sorter:

```
hash.sort(&lambda{ |o1,o2| o1 <=> o2 }).map(&:last).join(', ')
#⇒ "one, two, three"
```

Hope it helps.